# Hibernate: lazy loading vs dtos

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

Imagine having an JPA entity with different lazy loaded fields

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "organisation_teams",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "usr_organisation"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "usr_teams")
)
private Set<Team> teams = new LinkedHashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "organisation_associations",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "usr_organisation"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "organisation")
)
private Set<Organisation> children = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

This entity is now requested by a second service, so we need to convert into a DTO and return via REST for example. Now there can be different scenarios, where for example only the **team** field is required, only the **children** field or both.

One could map them always into the DTO, in this case using lazy loading is pointless in my opinion. Are there different elegant options aside of creating different DTOs (containing only the **team** or only the **children** fields) and different REST endpoints? I don`t think this would be an elegant solution as well, because you would end up with a bunch of endpoints and dtos.

Additionally Team and Organisation again have lazy loaded fields and the same issue applies again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for might be https://graphql.org/. But for plain REST endpoints I would say different DTOs is the way to go, use inheritance to avoid code duplication.

If you want to improve performance and not lazy load related entities you can specify different named entity graphs and depending on the DTO select the one that eagre loads the required data. See the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm.

Any lazy loaded field that is not mapped to a DTO won't be loaded. So basically you use the same entity with different graphs and different DTOs.

Comment: Thats a perfect hint, I took a look at netflix-dgs and it covers everything we need. Thanks!

Comment: That's what I've used so far, and Apollo in the Angular frontend.

Comment: Our backend is based on an RPC framework that we have written. So even the Angular middleware is retrieving the data using RPC calls. With DSG its a perfect fit without any refactoring required. We could cover REST Apis and RPC with the same GraphQL structure which is quite nice. Currently i think it would make sense to have a central GraphQL instance that forwards the requests to the correlating microservices and collects all data required.

Comment: With Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views and the Netflix DGS integration(https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#usage-4) it will be a breeze to integrate this into your application. See the example app here: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/tree/main/examples/spring-data-dgs